# How to format org-download's image saving directory(s)?

Tags: org-mode, directories

Suppose following org-file (`some_random_name.org`) that has 2 images with inserted from **org-download**.

```org
* heading 1
#+DOWNLOADED: /tmp/xls/xl/media/image2_stage2.png @ 2023-02-24 17:36:38
[[file:heading_1/2023-02-24_17-36-38_image2_stage2.png]]

* Second heading 2

#+DOWNLOADED: /tmp/xls/xl/media/image2_stage4.png @ 2023-02-24 17:37:06
[[file:Second_heading_2/2023-02-24_17-37-06_image2_stage4.png]]
```

By default, **org-download** puts these 2 images as following:

```
.
├── heading_1
│   └── 2023-02-24_17-36-38_image2_stage2.png
├── Second_heading_2
│   └── 2023-02-24_17-37-06_image2_stage4.png
└── some_random_name.org
```

This is great structure. However, all of my org-files exist in same directory. Consequently, it's structure is a mess. (can't find which directories are associated with which org-file.)

**Question** How can I make directories created by org-download into single parent directory (with same name as the org-file) ? (i.e. following structure):

```
.
├── some_random_name
│   ├── heading_1
│   │   └── 2023-02-24_17-36-38_image2_stage2.png
│   └── Second_heading_2
│       └── 2023-02-24_17-37-06_image2_stage4.png
└── some_random_name.org
```

Comment: Looks like you can set the `org-download-image-dir` variable for that. To set it per file, you could set it as a [file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)...

Comment: "... all of my org-files exist in same directory": there is no reason for all Org mode files to be in one directory, so you may rethink that (dis-)organization a bit. Most people organize them per project, There may be a file in each project that contributes to the agenda and it may be a good idea to put that file (or a link to it) in a single directory so that `org-agenda-files` can be populated easily; but for other files, e.g. docs, images, references, data files, computations, etc., I think the per-project organization wins hands down. And you can still use @dalanicolai's answer in each.

Comment: @NickD I use org-roam, by default it saves all files into same directory (and it seems changing that makes too much work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would prefer to set this via a [per-directory local-variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). They can be configured like [file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

In summary, you probably want to create a .dir-locals.el file in your org files directory and store the following code in there:

```lisp
((org-mode . ((eval . (setq org-download-image-dir (concat "./" (file-name-base buffer-file-name)))))))
```

Now for each org file you open in that directory, the local value of the `org-download-image-dir` automatically gets set to the file-name-base (see `C-h f` `file-name-base`).

I am not sure how the directory name should be provided. Here I am concating `"./"` and `(file-name-base buffer-file-name)`, because the `org-download-image-dir` docstring says that "." is the default value. Othwerise, I guess you can simply wrap the concat form in an `expand-file-name`.

Comment: Thank you very much, 2-answers to my 2 questions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply this everywhere, add the following hook into your init.el file:

```
    (defun my-org-download-set-dir ()
        "Set `org-download-image-dir` to the directory of the current 
        buffer's file."
        (setq-local org-download-image-dir (concat (file-name-directory 
        (buffer-file-name)) "/images/" (file-name-base buffer-file-name) "/") ))
    
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-download-set-dir)
```

Or if using use-package:

```
(use-package org-download
      :ensure t
      :config
    (defun my-org-download-set-dir ()
        "Set `org-download-image-dir` to the directory of the current 
        buffer's file."
        (setq-local org-download-image-dir (concat (file-name-directory 
        (buffer-file-name)) "/images/" (file-name-base buffer-file-name) "/") )) 
    
    :hook
      ((org-mode . my-org-download-set-dir))
```

This creates the following structure for all inserted images:

```
├─images
| └── buffer-file-name
│     ├── First_heading_1
│     │   └── img1.png
│     └── Second_heading_2
│         └── img2.png
└── buffer-file-name.org
```

If you want to add a folder next to the file with the same name then remove `"/images/"` from the hook and replace with `"/"`.

This will create the structure:

```
├─── buffer-file-name
│     ├── First_heading_1
│     │   └── img1.png
│     └── Second_heading_2
│         └── img2.png
└── buffer-file-name.org
```